# Switching from manual to automation testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, manual-testing

Hello Test Automation Experts, Managers,

Seeking advice on how to transit from Manual Testing to automation testing

I have been a manual tester for over 8 years. I wish to switch to automation testing hence I attended training in Selenium web driver and Java ( we used TestNG and Maven ). Though being able to write medium complex automation scripts I am finding it hard to get interviews or seek attention from a hiring manager or recruiter just by saying them I have knowledge in automation.

What should I do to get one step closer so that a hiring manager will show interest in me?

I am very much keen on moving to test automation and willing to spend the required time to make this happen.

Should I write a blog portraying my skills in automation or post my samples in Git hub?

Looking forward to receiving your advice as I am totally lost and frustrated last few months making this attempt switching to automation testing

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow is the right place to ask these questions, maybe ask your question at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could also try https://sqa.stackexchange.com.  There are similar questions answered there too.

Comment: ok thanks a lot , I will check these sites

Comment: thank you for sharing the site names :) i hope i will find some pointers there

Answer (score 2):

As most of the *Technocrats* from *Selenium*, *Mozilla*, *Google Chrome* and *IE* community are active and visits [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) on regular basis you can try the following ideas to get noticed :

- As a beginner go through the required *Discussion* threads within **Frequent** TAB on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and start getting your hands dirty with code.
- When you gather ample knowledge start *Answering* questions and become a *StackOverflow Volunteer*.
- Earn **Bronze**/**Silver**/**Gold** badges on **Selenium** / **WebDriver** / **Java** / **Python** / **C#** / **NodeJS** / **Ruby** / **PHP** / **Perl** tags.
- Start writing a *Technical Blog Site*
- Prepare Videos on *Technical Aspects* of **Selenium** / **WebDriver** / **Java** / **Python** / **C#** / **NodeJS** / **Ruby** / **PHP** / **Perl** and publish them.
- The best outcome can be, you can turn out to be a **Selenium Commiter**

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be:

1. To start with, try to write automation script for open web application. Example: Selenium script to login to Amazon, select a specific product, add to basket and go till payments page. Next automate some other sites.
2. Create a blog where to mention step by step how you achieved your task.
3. Upload your scripts to Github and provide that link in your block.
4. Ask and answer questions in stackoverflow. Be active in Facebook selenium/automation groups.
5. Practice java programming in sites like hackerrank, hackerearth, etc. Upload your solutions in github as well.
6. Explore deeper and deeper, keep giving interviews and never stop learning.
7. Update all your works as personal projects in your resume.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

[Click me to see Roadmap to become automation tester.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQlh5.png)

Click above pic and just have a look at it and trust me this is applicable for all type of candidate(Fresher/Experienced). Follow above image and you can be able to become automation tester from manual.